# Eloquent first with a custom defined preference order

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a shorter & elegant way to instruct the first method in eloquent to pick up the matching records using a custom preference order?

**Example:** ( pick up config A then B then Default )

```
$config = Configs::whereIn('section', ['A','B', 'default'])
    ->first() // Picks A or B or default;
```

To eliminate having to write a code like the following

```
    $config = Configs::where('section', 'A');

    if(!$config)
        config = Configs::where('section', 'B');
    elseif(!$config)
        config = Configs::where('section', 'default');
```

Comment: Did you try including an `orderBy()` before `->first()`? Remember that `->first()` simply returns the "first" row returned, based on the default sorting logic (typically via `id`, or whatever the primary key is)

Comment: I would like the query to get me the record matching the A value then B or default, they could have different incremental ids.

Comment: Is the expected result a fallback, according to the order specified in the `whereIn` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply provide some ordering based on `section` and `->first()` will select the "correct" record:

```php
$config = Configs::whereIn('section', ['A', 'B', 'default'])
->orderBy('section')
->first();
```

If `section: A` is present, then `$config` will be `A`, will an implicit fallback to `section: B` or `section: default` based on ordering.

Edit: `Config:: -> Configs::`, but remember, Laravel Model names are Singular by convention.

Comment: Orderby will sort them alphabetically, what about if those values were not alphabetical, Z, X, default ??

Comment: Then you'll need to include some kind of custom sort logic, like a `CASE` statement.  `orderByRaw('CASE WHEN section = 'Z' THEN 1 WHEN section = 'X' THEN 2 WHEN section = 'default' THEN 3 END')`, or similar.

Comment: If you have odd edge cases, please try to include those in your original question. We can only really provide answers based on the information given.